# getting console log this function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm really new to web programming.

1. Is this function React, JSX, or others?
2. How do I get console log from this function? For example, printing out children and/or router values to console log.
3. I'd like to hide 'prev' when current page is a specific page. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

```js
const App = ({children, router}) => (
<div className="App">
    <Stepper/>

    <div className='App-main'>
      <Row gutter={40}>
        <Col span={20}>
          { children }
        </Col>
        <Col span={4}>
          <Navigator
            label={label(router.location.pathname)}
            action={action(router, router.location.pathname)}
            prev={prev(router.location.pathname)}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: React/JSX. You should look at the documentation for the React library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As Zfrisch mentioned, it's a mix. App is a functional component (React), the stuff returned in the function is XML.
2. The rounded brackets are an implicit return. If you change it to curly braces, you can do stuff then return ( xmlGoeshere ); Example:

   ```
   const App = ({children, router}) => {
       console.log("hello world");
       return (
           <div className="App">
           etc...
       );
   };
   ```
3. It's hard to answer this in a way that works for you without more info. You can either use a ternary to make prev falsy, you can change the prev function, or modify the Navigator's render depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  Your suggestions are enough for me to resolve the issue.